problemas con docker swarm y 5 nodos
tengo 5 nodos en mi docker swarm, 3 manager y 2 worker, necesito desplegar una imagen desde docker stack (todo configurado en un docker-compose.yml), 5 nodos, uno para cada nodo sin importar que sea worker o manager
intente configurar el compose con
deploy:
mode: replicated
replicas: 5
placement:
constraints: [node.role == manager || node.role == worker]
este no me realizo las replicas
tambien asi:
deploy:
mode: replicated
replicas: 5
este solo desplego 5 contenedores en mi manager-1
deploy:
  mode: global

asi el docker intenta desplegar en cada nodo y me dan rejected
mi pregunta es como debo configurar el docker compose.yml para que replique a cada nodo
